# How to debug fgetcsv function in php?

Tags: php, fgetcsv

I have a problem in using `fgetcsv` function. The problem is the exact code works in my local, but not in server. Following is the code:

```
if (($handle = fopen("tmp/".$xlsfile, "r")) !== FALSE) {
    $data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",");
    ...
}
```

When debugged, print_r of $handle returns something (resource #99), but print_r $data returns nothing.

This is a bit weird for me, because the exact same code and .csv file work when I test locally.  The upload csv function works because I can see that the file gets uploaded, and fopen returns the right value.

The only difference that I notice is, in that page, the live server uses https, but I dont't think this should be a problem because the file gets uploaded, and fopen is successfull.

Anybody has an idea?

UPDATE [SOLVED] :
I have found the solution, its because in live server, this page uses https, but the form url for submitting the csv file was without https in the front.

Comment: Give full permission to the cvs file.

Comment: can you check `"tmp/".$xlsfile` is lead to an exist file?

Comment: Yes, the file does exist, i did checked. And the fact than fopen successful seems to confirm this.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this:

```
//give permission then do
$file = fopen("your_file.csv","r");
print_r(fgetcsv($file));
fclose($file);
```